# Why does pip say "No module named commands.install"?

Tags: python, windows, installation, pygame, pip

I have installed pip, and I have moved my directory in cmd to C:\Python27\Scripts. I try this code:
'`pip install whatever.whl`'

---

It says at the bottom of random code(looks like python):

---

'`ImportError: No module named commands.install`'
What is happening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this problem under another situation by uninstalling the offending package. You may try:

```
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

Here is my log:

```
sam@sam:~$ sudo pip install protobuf --upgrade
The directory '/home/sam/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/sam/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting protobuf
  Downloading protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz (188kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 188kB 194kB/s 
Collecting setuptools (from protobuf)
  Downloading setuptools-18.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 462kB 940kB/s 
Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf
  Found existing installation: setuptools 18.4
    Uninstalling setuptools-18.4:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-18.4
  Rolling back uninstall of setuptools
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 803, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 998, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 242, in move_wheel_files
    name, user=user, home=home, root=root, isolated=isolated
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 183, in distutils_scheme
    i = d.get_command_obj('install', create=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 845, in get_command_obj
    klass = self.get_command_class(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 430, in get_command_class
    self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named command.install
sam@sam:~$

sam@sam:~$ sudo pip install -U setuptools
The directory '/home/sam/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/sam/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading setuptools-18.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (462kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 462kB 1.3MB/s 
Installing collected packages: setuptools
  Found existing installation: setuptools 18.4
    Uninstalling setuptools-18.4:
      Successfully uninstalled setuptools-18.4
Successfully installed setuptools-18.5
sam@sam:~$ 
sam@sam:~$ sudo pip install protobuf --upgrade
The directory '/home/sam/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/sam/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting protobuf
  Downloading protobuf-2.6.1.tar.gz (188kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 188kB 214kB/s 
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from protobuf)
Installing collected packages: protobuf
  Found existing installation: protobuf 2.4.1
    Uninstalling protobuf-2.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled protobuf-2.4.1
  Running setup.py install for protobuf
Successfully installed protobuf-2.6.1
sam@sam:~$
```

Comment: For future reference `install -U` is not Uninstall but Upgrade. The output of the command is confusing because it prominently displays a message 'Successfully uninstalled foo'

Answer (score -1):

why do you use the extension?

From pip doc:

```
$ pip install SomePackage            # latest version
$ pip install SomePackage==1.0.4     # specific version
$ pip install 'SomePackage>=1.0.4'     # minimum version
```

Please take a look here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#examples

Answer (score -2):

The best solution to all pip problems is that you newly install python 2.7.9 and then run it. Otherwise, your exact problem can be very hard to track down.